# Удаление аттрибута

Tags: атрибуты, javascript, html, dom

Код:

```
document.getElementById('i1').onmouseover = "";
```

Почему-то не работает. Просто ничего не меняет, никаких ошибок не пишет. Как исправить?

**UPDATE1** Причина найдена - команды из функции не могут поменять содержимое переменной, заявленной вне. Но как исправить - пока вопрос

Comment: а что вы сделать то хотите? попробуйте `document.getElementById('i1').onmouseover = function(){ alert(this)};`

Comment: Так мне надо наоборот удалить действие. В итоге должно появиться onmouseover=""

Comment: элементарно:

    document.getElementById('i1').onmouseover = void 0;

Comment: @Spectre элементарно, но не работает

Comment: если переменную не видно, то засуньте её в пространство `window`. `window.variable = ''`

Comment: откройте консоль прям на этой странице, напишите: 

    document.getElementById('comment-tools-165133').onmouseover = console.log

понаводите несколько раз на кнопку "добавить комментарий", посмотрите, что выводит в консоль, потом сделайте 
 
    document.getElementById('comment-tools-165133').onmouseover = void 0;

понаводите на туже кнопку, что в консоли?

Comment: Переменную видно, проблема в другом. Объясняю на простом примере:

    var a = 1;
    function abc() { a = 2; }
    abc();
    document.write(a);
Что выведет этот код? 1! И это несмотря на то, что в функции меняем значение на 2.

Comment: 1 действие - пишет function log() { [native code] }
2 - пусто
3 - кнопка перестала подсвечиваться + пусто

Comment: @danpetruk, предложенный вами код мне выводит 2! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('i1').removeAttribute('onmouseover');
```

Если используется JQuery, То Я бы попробовал так:

```
$('#i1').attr('onmouseover', null);
```

Answer (score 1):

я бы попробовал поменять через **.attr("onmouseover","")**, потом сделать что-нибудь типа **.unbind("mouseenter")**, а потом прикрепить новое событие через **.on("mouseenter")**

Comment: автор использует чистый JS

Comment: поколение, выросшее на фреймворках, не знающее нативных методов.